# jQuery Change Image on Scroll at Responsive Breakpoint

Tags: jquery, if-statement, scroll, responsiveness

I have a script working fine that changes an image / logo on scroll, but I only want this to fire if the browser window is more than 767px - otherwise nothing/keep 'as is'. How can I modify this script to achieve that please:-

```
 jQuery(function($) {
//caches a jQuery object containing the brand image element
var brandimg = $(".x-brand img");
$(window).scroll(function() {
var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
 // if( $(window).width() > 767 {
  if (scroll >= 40) {
        brandimg.attr('src', 'logo-icon.png');
        brandimg.removeClass('x-img-1').addClass("img-2");
    } else {
      brandimg.attr('src', 'logo-full.png').addClass("logo-full");
      brandimg.removeClass("x-img-2").addClass('img-1');
    }
});
});
```

I can't use a media query here as the 'Wordpress' theme uses an image rather than image background.

Not sure perhaps an additional if statement surround the current function?

Thanks

Glennyboy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I did it in the end:-

```
jQuery(function($) {
//caches a jQuery object containing the brand image element
var brandimg = $(".x-brand img");
jQuery(window).on("focus load resize scroll",function(e){
var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
if (($(window).width() < 460) || (scroll >= 40)) {
        brandimg.attr('src', 'logo-icon.png');
        brandimg.removeClass('x-img-1').addClass("x-img-2");
    } else {
      brandimg.attr('src', 'logo-full.png').addClass("logo-full");
      brandimg.removeClass("x-img-2").addClass('x-img-1');
    }
});
});
```

And it works perfectly for scroll and window size on load, resize and scroll